# Rotating a vector through a certain angle in a certain axis

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, rotations

I know how to find the linear transformation with angle rotation, but I don't know how it can be applied to a vector only in a certain axis.

For example: rotation of $v = [5, 2, 3]^T$ about the z-axis through the angle $5pi/6$

I can find the linear transformation of the z-axis:

cos 150  -sin 150 
sin 150  cos 150

But I don't know how to apply it to the vector v when it's rotating about the z-axis.

Please help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula

Comment: What is the linear transformation of the z-axis? You are giving the matrix of rotation, and that is what you want.

Comment: Do you know how to construct a rotation in 2-d? Well, this is a rotation in the $x$-$y$ plane. Embed that in a 3x3 matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $M$ of the transformation is $3\times 3$. We can obtain this matrix by considering the image of $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and  $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

The image of $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is  $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta \\ \sin \theta \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. This is the first column of $M$.

The image of $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is  $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta) \\ \sin (\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta) \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -\sin\theta \\ \cos \theta \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. This is the second column of $M$.

The image of $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is  $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. This is the third column of $M$.

$$M=\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta &0 \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta &0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

The image of $v$ is

$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos150^\circ & -\sin150^\circ &0 \\ \sin150^\circ & \cos150^\circ &0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{3} & -1 &0 \\ 1 & -\sqrt{3} &0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} -5\sqrt{3}-2 \\ 5-2\sqrt{3} \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$$